# An exercise about Weierstrass theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Q:$\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}f_{n}\left( x\right)$ is a series of holomorphic functions on region D, and if $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\operatorname{Re}f_{n}\left( x\right)$ is compact uniform convergence on D, then either $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\operatorname{Im}f_{n}\left( x\right)$ is compact uniform convergence on D or it diverges on everywhere in D .

I tried to prove that if there is $z_{0}$ in D such that $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}f_{n}(z_{0})$ converges, then $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}f_{n}\left( x\right)$ is compact uniform convergence in D

To wit, if there is N , for all m>n>N,for all z in K,$\left| \sum ^{m}_{n+1}f_{n}\left( z\right) \right|<\varepsilon$

To wit,if there is N , for all m>n>N,for all z in K,$\left|\sum ^{m}_{n+1} \int _{z_{0}}^{z}f_{n}'\left( z\right) dz+f_{n}(z_{0}) \right|<\varepsilon$

and use Cauchy-Riemann equation

$f_{n}'\left( z\right) \ =\dfrac{\partial u_{n}\left( z\right) }{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial u_{n}\left( z\right) }{\partial y}$

But I find it hard to prove $\left|\sum ^{m}_{n+1} \int _{z_{0}}^{z}\dfrac{\partial u_{n}\left( z\right) }{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial u_{n}\left( z\right) }{\partial y} \right|<\varepsilon$

Comment: I have no idea what your background preparation is, so the following comment may or may not be helpful: the "PDE"-proof of this fact often uses the [Borel-Caratheodory Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Carath%C3%A9odory_theorem) for holomorphic functions, and which is a special version of Harnack's inequalities for elliptic PDEs.

Comment: you need to use Borel Caratheodory which estimates the absolute value of a holomorphic function in terms of the real part and the value at a point; then fixing $z_0$ and considering $g_n(z)=f_n(z)-f(z_0)$ one can show that $g_n$ converges normally on the maximal disc centered at $z_0$ and included in your domain and then a connexity argument shows the same result for the whole of the domain; after that, either $f_n(z_0)$ converges so $f_n$ does too or $f_n(z_0)$ diverges so $f_n$ does same everywhere too

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to Borel-Caratheodory that bypasses potential theory.

**Notation.** Henceforth the arrow $\to$ means  *locally uniformly, on compact subsets of $D$.*

The partial sum $\sum_{k=0}^n f_n(z)= F_n(z) = U_n + i V_n$ has the property that $U_n\to U(z)$. The exponentiated  sequence $G_n(z)= e^{F_n(z)}$ satisfies the condition that $|G_n(z)| =e^{U_n(z)}\to e^{U(z)}$; thus the sequence $G_n(z)$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $D$. By Montel's Theorem there exists a convergent subsequence $ G_{n_m}(z) :=H_mz)\to H(z)$. By Cauchy estimates, the derivatives  $H'_m(z)\to H'(z)$ also. Note that $|H(z)|= e^U$ is locally bounded away from zero.

Thus  $ F_{n_m}=H_m'/H_m  \to H'/H$.
The imaginary part of this identity tells us that the **subsequence** $Im(F_{n_m})= V_
{n_m}$ is locally uniformly convergent.

If the invocation of Montel produces a rival subsequence $\tilde H_m$ that has a genuinely different limit $\tilde H(z) =\tilde U + i \tilde V$, then since $|H(z)|= |\tilde H (z)|= e^{U(z)}$, the quotient $H(z)/\tilde H(z) = e^{ i \alpha}$ is a constant function, a unit-length complex number that is not unity.  In this case one sees that  $V(z)= \tilde V(z)+ \alpha$.  Thus  the two subsequences of partial sums $V_{n_m}(z)$ and $\tilde V_{n_m}$  diverge at every $z\in D$.